# How to display the calculated value only one time using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query :

`

```
select e.empid, convert(char(5), tr.In_Time, 108) as In_time, 
        convert(char(5), tr.Out_Time, 108) as Out_time,
        convert(varchar(5), sum(datediff(minute, trr.In_Time, isnull(trr.Out_Time,       null))) / 60)
        + ':' +
        convert(varchar(5),sum(datediff(minute, trr.In_Time, isnull(trr.Out_Time,null))) % 60)
   as TotalHours,  

  from EMPLOYEES e
 Left Join EMPLOYEE_TIME tr
    on (e.empid=tr.empid)
 Left Join EMPLOYEE_TIME trr
    on (e.empid=trr.empid)
 where (
            trr.In_Time BETWEEN '2013-09-11' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-11')
            and  tr.In_Time BETWEEN '2013-09-11' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1,  '2013-09-11')
        )  group by e.empid, tr.In_Time, tr.Out_Time e.JoiningDate    order  by e.JoiningDate ASC
```

`

After executing above query, i get the following result :
`

```
EmpID        in_time            out_time            totalhours  
1           9:30                18:00                   8:30  
2           10:00               13:00                   8:00  
2           14:00               19:00  
3           10:30               13:30                   3:00  
3           14:30               NULL                    3:00
```

`

But i don't want to print the **totalhours** twice when multiple time entry **Out_time is Null**, as like below :

`

```
EmpID        in_time            out_time            totalhours  
1           9:30                18:00                   8:30  
2           10:00               13:00                   8:00  
2           14:00               19:00  
3           10:30               13:30                   3:00  
3           14:30               NULL
```

`

Could anybody please help me? thanks in advance

**WORKING SQL**

```
SELECT  e.empid ,
        CONVERT(CHAR(5), tr.In_Time, 108) AS In_time ,
        CONVERT(CHAR(5), tr.Out_Time, 108) AS Out_time ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, trr.In_Time,
                                         ISNULL(trr.Out_Time, NULL))) / 60)
        + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, trr.In_Time,
                                                 ISNULL(trr.Out_Time, NULL)))
        % 60) AS TotalHours
FROM    EMPLOYEES e
        LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_TIME tr ON ( e.empid = tr.empid )
        LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_TIME trr ON ( e.empid = trr.empid )
WHERE   ( trr.In_Time BETWEEN '2013-09-11'
                      AND     DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-11')
          AND tr.In_Time BETWEEN '2013-09-11'
                         AND     DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-11')
        )
GROUP BY e.empid ,
        tr.In_Time ,
        tr.Out_Time ,
        e.JoiningDate
ORDER BY e.JoiningDate ASC
```

Comment: This SQL won't work, you're missing a coma `tr.Out_Time e.JoiningDate` and you have a coma here `as TotalHours, from EMPLOYEES e` when you don't need one.  I have added the fixed SQL at the bottom, use this instead of what you have posted if you're happy with it.

Comment: Why do you need `isnull(..., null)`?

Comment: @christiandev thanks and sorry, while posting missed it

Comment: @dasblinkenlight previously it was requirement to print some default time if null , but now it has changed , so i kept it null for time being

Answer (score 0):

JUST USE CASE WHEN

LIKE

```
CASE WHEN Out_Time IS NOT NULL THEN convert(varchar(5),sum(datediff(minute, trr.In_Time, isnull(trr.Out_Time,null))) % 60)
    ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: i want to display totalhours only once on the first row of every empid, regardless of how many in_time and out_time have entered for particular empid.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it seems that you only want the hours on the first row for each `EmpID`.  (If not, please update the question with additional data that are exceptions to this.)

Assuming this, here is a method using `row_number()`:

```
with yourquery as (<your query here>)
select EmpID, in_time, out_time,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then totalhours end) as totalhours
from (select yq.*,
             row_number() over (partition by EmpId order by in_time) as seqnum
      from yourquery yq
     ) yq;
```

EDIT:

This is what it should look like:

```
with yourquery as (
    SELECT  e.empid ,
            CONVERT(CHAR(5), tr.In_Time, 108) AS In_time ,
            CONVERT(CHAR(5), tr.Out_Time, 108) AS Out_time ,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, trr.In_Time,
                                             ISNULL(trr.Out_Time, NULL))) / 60)
            + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, trr.In_Time,
                                                     ISNULL(trr.Out_Time, NULL)))
            % 60) AS TotalHours
    FROM    EMPLOYEES e
            LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_TIME tr ON ( e.empid = tr.empid )
            LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_TIME trr ON ( e.empid = trr.empid )
    WHERE   ( trr.In_Time BETWEEN '2013-09-11'
                          AND     DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-11')
              AND tr.In_Time BETWEEN '2013-09-11'
                             AND     DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2013-09-11')
            )
    GROUP BY e.empid ,
            tr.In_Time ,
            tr.Out_Time ,
            e.JoiningDate
    )
select yq.EmpID, yq.in_time, yq.out_time,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then yq.totalhours end) as totalhours
from (select yq.*,
             row_number() over (partition by yq.EmpId order by in_time) as seqnum
      from yourquery yq
     ) yq
ORDER BY yq.JoiningDate ASC
```

Comment: yes i want as you told. When i put my whole above query in <your query here>, but error showing _The multi-part identifier "e.empid" could not be bound._

Comment: @user2640518 . . . See the query with the substitution.

Comment: thanks a lot :), now this query runs fine, but could you please help me here,why unmatched records is not displaying from left table _EMPLOYEES_ as i am using Left Join

Comment: @user2640518 . . . It is not showing up because the `where` clause is using conditions on the right tables in the left outer join -- turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.  Just replace the `where` with `and` so they become part of the `on` clause.

Comment: i replaced `where` with `and` then i tried but there is no affect of date condition, it displays all the records of the table(E.g. if 200 employees is there and 150 employees was present on specific date, then it should display 200 records(assumed), but it displays all the records 6000 records(assumed))